# Discrete Mathematics - Probability Word Problem

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Question: In $1992$, after game 1 of the World Series (of baseball, a best-of-seven series), the announcers took pleasure in announcing that over the previous $20$ years, it had only happened $8$ times that the team that lost the first game went on to win the series. They seemed to be suggesting that winning a series $40$% of the time was surprisingly low after loosing the first game. Is it? In other words, assuming that the two teams are equally likely to win a game and that the games are independent events, what is the probability that the team that lost the first game wins the series?

*I can't seem to understand the problem and what I'm supposed to solve. If anyone can help me out, I'd appreciate it, thanks.

Comment: Consider coin flips and Pascal's triangle.  I am not allowed to give you an answer unless you show work.  By the way, you should **totally ignore** the sportscaster's indication of surprise, which is based on the idea that the events are **dependent**, re home-field, the psychology of playing with your back to the wall, ...

Comment: What is the probability that a team wins at least $4$ out of $6$ coin-flip games?  That's what it takes, under the given assumptions, for a team that has lost the first game to come back to win the Series.  That's what you're being asked to figure out.  So that you can check your work, I think the answer is $\frac{11}{32}$.

Comment: In the actual event, the Blue Jays did lose the first game against Atlanta, but won the whole series.